# Camel EIP Request/Reply (in-out), how to 'fast fail' a route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have my camel setup along the lines of:

```
<route>
  <from ur="servlet:///test"/>
  <to uri="direct:check1"/>
  <to uri="direct:check2"/>
  <to uri="direct:check3"/>
  <to uri="direct:myprocessor"/>
</route>
```

Since I'm setting this up as a request/reply (in-out) pattern, I'm confused around if there is a process-stopping issue on check1, 2, or 3 on one specific message/exchange how to 'fast fail' a response back without going through the rest of the routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing exceptions and using the [onException DSL](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) will achieve what you need. If you throw an exception in one of the checks it will be caught in the onException block without going further through the rest of the route.

Comment: Confirm;  if throwing exceptions is the only way to handle a 'fast fail' scenario, at least it is working :-)